# VPN connection disabled in vista

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, vpn

VPN connection in vista is disabled with the message like "you need active internet connection"... but i'm connected to the internet.

Same issue in win7 I'm regularly solving just opening and closing properties of VPN... in vista this method failed. Last time I enabled connection after 10 min of random clickin on different properties many times and refreshing )

There is any stable way to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcut to the VPN connection solves the problem ) it can be opened whatever happens with my connection.